# Как делать api карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь научиться делать api карты и опять не могу сдвинуться с места.
На примере "Маршрут от местоположения пользователя" описанного тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocated_multiroute
Вот тестовая страница сайта
http://krasnodarskii-krai.ru/prolozhit-marshrut.html
В нее я вставил:

```
<title>Примеры. Маршрут от местоположения пользователя</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="krasnodarskii-krai.ru/upload/maps/geolocated_multiroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    html, body, #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

И по адресу krasnodarskii-krai.ru/upload/maps/ лежит файл geolocated_multiroute.js с содержимым:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
    zoom: 9,
    // Добавим кнопку для построения маршрутов на карту.
    controls: ['routeButtonControl']
  });

  var control = myMap.controls.get('routeButtonControl');

  // Зададим координаты пункта отправления с помощью геолокации.
  control.routePanel.geolocate('from');

  // Откроем панель для построения маршрутов.
  control.state.set('expanded', true);
});
```

И карты нет.
Расскажите, пожалуйста подробно, как нужно сделать правильно.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но вопрос не решен.
Кто-то может подробно растолковать куда что вставлять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенной странице не хватает элемента с `id="map`. Именно в этом элементе и будет отображаться карта. И убедиться, что размеры этого элемента не нулевые

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ..........
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
    zoom: 9,
    // Добавим кнопку для построения маршрутов на карту.
    controls: ['routeButtonControl']
  });

  var control = myMap.controls.get('routeButtonControl');

  // Зададим координаты пункта отправления с помощью геолокации.
  control.routePanel.geolocate('from');

  // Откроем панель для построения маршрутов.
  control.state.set('expanded', true);
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Можно подробнее? Какой код вставить в указанную страницу, а какой в файл geolocated_multiroute.js?  Или может еще что-то нужно вставлять в style.css? И куда вот это #map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

Comment: Вы мне привели 4 куска кода, которые я уже много раз видел. Но яснее не стало. В каких файлах каждый из них должен быть?

Comment: @Сергей Что значит "куда вставлять"? Стили к стилям, скрипты к скриптам, разметку к размтке

Comment: @Сергей Вашу главную ошибку я указал `В приведенной странице не хватает элемента с id="map"`

Comment: Спасибо. Все получилось.

Comment: @Сергей Если мой ответ помог Вам, то отметьте его как верный